# How to edit some parts of text files c++? (Mac OS)

Tags: c++, macos

Lets say I have a **.txt** file that says:

```
Date: 01:10:21
Hi
My name is Jack
```

and I want to change `My name is Jack` to `My name is John`! but instead of change everything like:

```
file.open("yourname.txt", ios::out);
if (file.is_open()) {
  file << "Date: 01:10:21 \nHi \nMy name is John";
  file.close();
}
```

I want to edit only the `Jack` part to `John`, Because the date could be changed later that time, so how can I do it?

Every help appreciated!

Comment: You kind of have to do it like that. Read the input file, make the changes, write a temp output file. And then rename the old file to a backup name, rename the temp file to your original name. And then delete backup. Then at least you won't lose data if at any point something fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't say I know a proper C++ way, but there is a C way using `<cstdio>`. Here is a snippet how this is achieved, however you need to implement your own logic for the problem, like finding where and how much to replace, ex. use indexes or string buffer to hold your needed data. Here is a minimum snippet:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>

int main() {
    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r+");

    if (!fp)
        return -1;

    int c;
    char buffer[30] = {0};

    while (fgets(buffer, 3 /*hold `is `*/, fp)) {
        printf("[%s]\r\n", buffer);

        if (!strcmp(buffer, "is")) { //match `is` for example
            fgetc(fp); // control the file ptr and move one forward
            fputs("JOHN", fp); //replace
            break;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, let me get this right! you just modify the word letter by letter? (char by char) I mean C looks so similar to C++ so thanks but I just have to get the logic right

Comment: You can use `fputs("JOHN")` for strings, it's a sample to see how it works and how can be used.

Comment: I've added a more detailed example for your clarity, hope that makes the things more clear.

Comment: oh ok thank you so much.

Comment: Just make sure to flag or vote answers to be helpful for the community. Regards.